# How project to a new Type that has a Count of some other entity without the navigation property

Tags: c#, automapper

How do I use Automapper to Project the `Blog` to `BlogListItemDto` but without the navigation property?
for example

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}

    //public IList<Post> Posts{get;set;}  with out this properties
}

public class Post
{ 
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public int BlogId {get;set;} 
    public Blog Blog{get;set;} 
    ... 
}


// and here's the dto
public class BlogListItemDto
{
    public int Id{get;set;}
    public string Title{get;set;}
    public int PostCount{get;et;} // how I get this property to project
}
```

I can do it without automapper `db.Blog.Select(b=>new BlogListTiemDto{ Id=b.Id,Title = b.Title, PostCount = db.Post.Where(p=>p.BlogId == b.Id).Count() })`

Comment: Would this not work:  `var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => { cfg.CreateMap<Blog, BlogListItemDto>().
                ForMember( dest =>dest.PostCount, opt=>opt.MapFrom(src=>db.Post.Where(p=>p.BlogId == db.blog.Id)) ); });`, assuming you will have to inject a reference to the DB object in the mapping code.

Comment: this may work , however I use `Profile` class，and DI not work well with the `Profile` class

Comment: I have not used automapper much, but have a look at this: https://jan-v.nl/post/using-dependency-injection-in-your-automapper-profile

Comment: @peeyushsingh I wonder if there a way that  can work with the `memebersToExpand` parameters